# golang how to parse time without year, but default to current year

Tags: go, time

If I have a string such as today's date, in the format "Today is Wed Jun 30", I can parse it with:

`time.Parse("Today is Mon, Jan 2")`

The year is not included, and so it is defaulted to 0000.
How do I get it to parse the date and default to the current year? I can think of some ugly workarounds, like getting the year and appending it to the string and then parsing it again, but I'm guessing there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the current year to the result of parsing the string:

```
t, err := time.Parse("Today is Mon, Jan 2", "Today is Wed, Jun 30")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
t = t.AddDate(time.Now().Year(), 0, 0)
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QgJSmDFQkQD).

Answer (score 1):

You can default to current year instead of 0000 by using `strings.Replace()` method but it require you doing some string conversion ,I have created a code depicting the same logic :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    t, err := time.Parse("Today is Mon, Jan 2", "Today is Thu, Jul 1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("t ", t)
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
    year := time.Now().Year()

    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(t.String(), "0000", strconv.Itoa(year), 1))

}
```

Output:

```
t  0000-07-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
2009-07-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set it right after you parse it.

```
t, err := time.Parse("Today is Mon, Jan 2", "Today is Mon, Jan 2")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
t = time.Date(time.Now().Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second(), t.Nanosecond(), t.Location())
```